# How to add quantity for each custom option?

Tags: product, custom-options

I have a product with different length. So I went to `Custom Options` to add the different lengths.

But for each length, I need it to have a different price and quantity. You can customize the price by default but no the quantity.

How do achieve this?

I tried grouping them but somehow Magento doesn't let me group products that have "Custom Options".

Also, feel free to give whatever solution that achieve the intended results, either via extension or coding. Thanks!

Comment: you can create the configurable products. for custom option you can add the options for product

Answer (score 1):

You can check this link to create the configurable product creation

[Configurable product](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product)